# Passing -it options to docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker and was experimenting with it.
I run a docker image as follows:-

`docker run -it -p 4000:4000 -p 5858:5858 -v /c/Users/a/b:/usr/src/test/ image-name /bin/bash`

and after running it I perform some copy operations inside the docker container.

Now I wanted to know is how to do it using docker-compose which will perform the copy operation itself depending upon the command specified by me and keep the terminal open.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to do is right [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/)

First create a Dockerfile and there you may put any 'copy operations' you want.

Example of a Dockerfile,

`FROM python:3.4-alpine
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "app.py"]`

Answer (score 0):

**Mounting Volume**, you need to make sure to have data that you want to copy to in "b" folder as below **volumes**, so that it will be available in test/ in container.

Here is your compose file.

```
version: '2'
services:
  service-name:
    image: image-name:latest
    ports:
     - 4000:4000
     - 5858:5858
    volumes:
     - /c/Users/a/b:/usr/src/test/
```

Use **COPY** command in **Dockerfile**, so that you don't need to mount your volume to the container.

> **Dockerfile**, below explains you how to run simple node application by copying the current directories

```
FROM node:boron

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json .
# For npm@5 or later, copy package-lock.json as well
# COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install

# First .(DOT) referes to current folder where the docker is, and second .(DOT) referes to teh folder where you want to copy

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```